# How to put text on the right side of an <h> tag?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm creating a site and I'm stuck at a probably simple thing. I have an `<h4>` tag that says something and I want on the same line but some spaces to the right to have a `<p>` tag with some text in it. Whatever I do it either gets the text exactly next to the `<h4>` tag or when I do something like `align:right` it puts it under the `<h4>` tag. Here is my code:

```html
<div class="col-md-8">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <h1 id="title">Education</h1>
        <h4 style="display: inline">University</h4>
        <p style="align=right"> 2009 - 2015<br></p>
        <p style="display: inline">B.Sc in Computer Science</p>
        <p style="display: inline"> Grades: 2:1</p>
        <span>
            <h4>Highschool</h4>
            <p>2006 - 2009</p>
        </span>   
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm using bootstrap to do the grid layout. I don't know if this plays a role in this problem.

Comment: Use bootstrap class  `text-right`, and set to `display: block`

Comment: It seems to work when I take out the display: inline tag, but it takes it to the next line and to the right, not on the same line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Without code structure change

Make the elements in the same line inline and just float your date range to the right.

```css
.title-right {
    float: right;
}

.title-left {
    display: inline;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-md-8">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <h1 id="title">Education</h1>
        <h4 class="title-left">University</h4>
        <span class="title-right"> 2009 - 2015</span>
        <span>B.Sc in Computer Science</span>
        <span> Grades: 2:1</span>
        <span>
            <h4>Highschool</h4>
            <p>2006 - 2009</p>
        </span>   
    </div>
</div>
```

This way you don't have to include the date range in the header like in [Maddy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34990768), which works, but it isn't proper HTML5 semantics, because you include stuff in the header that doesn't goes there.

Also a few more things to consider:

- Don't use paragraphs for things that are not paragraphs. You build up a line from multiple elements. That is what `<span>` is for. This way you also don't have to add `display:inline` everywhere.
- Don't use inline styles. Create classes and add the styling over there.

### Better code structure

#### Old school way

If you want to place everything in two column, just create `<div>`s for the lines and make the left side text inline while you float the right side text to the right.

```css
.float-right {
    float: right;
}

.inline {
    display: inline;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-md-8">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <h1 id="title">Education</h1>
        <div>
            <h4 class="inline">University</h4>
            <span class="float-right"> 2009 - 2015</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <span>B.Sc in Computer Science</span>
            <span class="float-right"> Grades: 2:1</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h4 class="inline">Highschool</h4>
            <p class="float-right">2006 - 2009</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### New school way

With the same DOM as in the previous section you can just slap a flexbox to the row and align the children to the sides. This solution assumes that you have only 2 children, one for each side.

```css
.side-layout {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-md-8">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <h1 id="title">Education</h1>
        <div class="side-layout">
            <h4>University</h4>
            <span> 2009 - 2015</span>
        </div>
        <div class="side-layout">
            <span>B.Sc in Computer Science</span>
            <span> Grades: 2:1</span>
        </div>
        <div class="side-layout">
            <h4>Highschool</h4>
            <p>2006 - 2009</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a span tag in `h4` (heading) tag.

```html
<div class="col-md-8">
  <h1 id="title">Education</h1>
  <h4 style="display: inline">University
    <span style="float:right"> 2009 - 2015</span>
  </h4>
  <p style="display: inline">B.Sc in Computer Science</p><p style="display: inline"> Grades: 2:1</p>
  <span>
    <h4>Highschool</h4>
    <p>2006 - 2009</p>
  </span>   
</div>
```

Comment: It kind of works. I made some modifications. I also want the B.Sc in Computer Science to work in the same way, so that the grades are on the right side but when I do it the same way. This <p> tag goes next to the <h4> tag `<div class="col-md-8">
      <h1 id="title">Education</h1>
      <h4 style="display: inline">University</h4>
          <p style="float:right">2009 - 2015</p>
  
      <p>B.Sc in Computer Science</p>
      <p style="float:right"> Grades: 2:1</p>
  
    <h4 style="display:inline">Highschool</h4>
    <p style="float:right">2006 - 2009</p>
   
</div>`